# AngulatJS Dynamic data not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

**HTML**

This is html file i had written and i repeat the column 3 with product image details

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
  <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
          <img src="../backend/uploads/{{user.image}}" width="200px" height="300px">
          <p>{{user.name}}</p>
          <span><strong>&#8377;{{user.price}}</strong></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**
I get data from php file but it becomes infinite loop

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

 //get data from php file

  $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'fetch_scroll.php'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        console.log($scope.users);
  });
   //function to load products

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var length = $scope.users.length;
    var last = $scope.users[length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
      $scope.users.push(last + i);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: No erros I received data in object format. It contains name,image and price

Comment: I got on erroe that is $scope.users is undefined in loadMore function

Comment: Get rid of infinite scroll, so as to isolate problem. Issue is likely there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$scope.loadMore` function is getting called **before** the `successCallback` function.

You can call that function after you get data from the server. Below code snippet might help:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

 //get data from php file

  $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'fetch_scroll.php'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        console.log($scope.users);

        // Added this inside the successCallback
        $scope.loadMore();
  });
   //function to load products

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var length = $scope.users.length;
    var last = $scope.users[length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
      $scope.users.push(last + i);
    }
  };
});
```